# Adjunct or Argument: "The bird flew over the lake"

Tags: linguistics, adjuncts, argument-structure

In the title sentence, does "over the lake" serve as an adjunct or an optional argument? Here are the tests I tried using, though they weren't very enlightening beyond giving what kind of argument it may or may not be:

> The Omission Test (included for the sake of thoroughness)
>   a. "The bird flew **over the lake**."
>   b. "The bird flew." — *over the lake* is not an obligatory argument.

---

> The Relative Clause Test:
>   a. "The bird flew **over the lake**."
>   b. "The bird flew, which occurred **over the lake**" — to me, this sounds off, which suggests that *over the lake* isn't an adjunct but in fact an optional argument.

---

> The "Do So" Test
>   a. "The bird flew **over the lake**, and the airplane *did so* across the ocean." — to me, this sounds fine, which suggests that *over the lake* isn't an argument but in fact an adjunct.

How is it that I'm getting these seemingly contradictory results? Might it have something to do with the sentence's telicity (i.e."over the lake" has the potential to indicate the location *or* the course of the bird's flight, depending on how you interpret things), or am I just misunderstanding something more fundamental in all this?

Any and all help is much appreciated~

Comment: There needs to be some context to show whether "over the lake" indicates *where* the bird was flying, or how it *crossed* the lake.

Comment: How are you defining adjunct and argument? It seems to me the “do so” test fails—unless the plane also flies across the lake.  But why does this matter?

Comment: "Over the lake" indicates directional movement and hence is a complement, not an adjunct. Such PPs need to be licensed by an appropriate verb, usually one of motion like "fly".

Comment: The argument vs adjunct debate is not settled. See the Wikipedia article for an overview. In the isoformal 'The boys sidled along the bench', deleting the PP is not an option. The issue is complex, and surface structures (and facile constituency tests) can be misleading.